# Error while installing package linux lowlatency

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I am getting an error trying to install lowlatency package using

```
sudo apt-get install linux-lowlatency
```

For Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

The output is as follows.

```
Reading package lists... 
Building dependency tree... 
Reading state information... 
The following additional packages will be installed:

linux-headers-4.4.0-128-lowlatency linux-headers-lowlatency
linux-image-4.4.0-128-lowlatency linux-image-lowlatency 
Suggested packages:
fdutils linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
    linux-headers-4.4.0-128-lowlatency linux-headers-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.4.0-128-lowlatency linux-image-lowlatency linux lowlatency
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 77 not upgraded.

Need to get 6,708 B/59.5 MB of archives.  After this operation, 230 MB of additional disk space will be used.  Do you want to continue? [Y/n]  
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 linux-headers-lowlatency amd64 4.4.0.128.134   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 linux-  image-lowlatency amd64 4.4.0.128.134

Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 linux-  lowlatency amd64 4.4.0.128.134

Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 linux- headers-lowlatency amd64 4.4.0.128.134   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 linux- image-lowlatency amd64 4.4.0.128.134   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 linux- lowlatency amd64 4.4.0.128.134   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
```

Before someone tells me to upgrade I have another machine with identical hardware operating on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS and the same command worked no problem.

The machine that works has an IP address of 192.168.4.89

The machine that does not work has an IP address of 192.168.4.40

Comment: I suspect it's some bad cached apt-data. Try "sudo apt-get clean" and "sudo apt-get autoclean" then follow by "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get install linux-lowlatency"

Comment: One difference is that the "other" machine is connected to the network. You're not. The "`404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]`" means "I can't connect"

Comment: It is our stupid network. The address that could not connect was 192.168.4.140 and not 40. I tried a static IP address (we have development IP addresses that we are allowed to use from 192.168.4.20 to 192.168.4.40 for engineering purposes) of 192.168.4.35 and the issue went away. I have a feeling that when the last byte of the IP address from DHCP is bigger than 99 I have seen this issue before.